В чем суть задания по java ооп
задание звучит так:

Без null. Создайте сущность Хранилище, которая обладает следующими
характеристиками:

Может хранить один произвольный объект в один момент времени.
Хранилище неизменяемо.
Объект кладется в Хранилище при его создании. В качестве объекта может быть сохранено также и значение null.
Хранилище может вернуть ссылку на Объект.
Если вместо объекта хранится null, необходимо вернуть какое-либо альтернативное значение.
Метод получения значения должен работать с тем типом данных, который был указан во время создания объекта Выполните следующие задания:
Создайте Хранилище чисел, положите туда значение null. Передайте Хранилище в какой- либо метод, извлеките значение, и выведите его на
экран. Альтернативой должно быть число 0.





Создайте Хранилище чисел, положите туда значение 99. Передайте Хранилище в какой- либо метод, извлеките значение, и выведите его на
экран. Альтернативой должно быть число -1.
Создайте Хранилище строк, положите туда значение null. Передайте Хранилище в какой- либо метод, извлеките значение, и выведите его на
экран. Альтернативой должна быть строка “default”.
Создайте Хранилище строк, положите туда значение “hello”. Передайте Хранилище в какой-либо метод, извлеките значение, и выведите его на
экран. Альтернативой должна быть строка “hello world”.


моя реализация:
public class Storage<T> {
    private final T item; // Хранимый объект
    private final T alternative; // Альтернативное значение

    // Конструктор хранилища
    public Storage(T item, T alternative) {
        this.item = item;
        this.alternative = alternative;
    }

    // Метод получения объекта из хранилища
    public T get() {
        return item != null ? item : alternative;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Пример 1: Хранилище чисел с null и альтернативой 0
        Storage<Integer> storageWithNullNumber = new Storage<>(null, 0);
        processStorage(storageWithNullNumber); // Ожидается вывод 0

        // Пример 2: Хранилище чисел со значением 99 и альтернативой -1
        Storage<Integer> storageWithNumber = new Storage<>(99, -1);
        processStorage(storageWithNumber); // Ожидается вывод 99

        // Пример 3: Хранилище строк с null и альтернативой "default"
        Storage<String> storageWithNullString = new Storage<>(null, "default");
        processStorage(storageWithNullString); // Ожидается вывод "default"

        // Пример 4: Хранилище строк со значением "hello" и альтернативой "hello world"
        Storage<String> storageWithString = new Storage<>("hello", "hello world");
        processStorage(storageWithString); // Ожидается вывод "hello"
    }

    // Универсальный метод обработки хранилища
    public static <T> void processStorage(Storage<T> storage) {
        System.out.println("Извлеченное значение: " + storage.get());
    }
}

Вроде похоже на правду, но я не знаю зачем передавать альтернативное значение, если передаем в хранилище hello, оно же не равно 0, и то же самое для 99
в чем суть задания, может я не правильно делаю

Наверное тут подразумевалось, что альтернативное значение будет хранится в статическом поле класса, чтобы не указывать его каждый раз, либо что альтернативное значение указыватся при извлечении хранимого значения.

Формально, представленная реализация хранилища отличается от задания тем, что она содержит два поля вместо одного.  То есть, нужно оставить одно поле в соответствии с заданием, тогда логику выбора объекта для хранения следует реализовать в конструкторе, а не в геттере.
Также класс хранилища следует объявить как финальный (final), чтобы он был неизменяемым.
Дополнительно, можно проверить, что альтернативное значение не содержит null, использовав Objects.requireNonNull (или аннотацию @NonNull).
С учётом вышесказанного, код можно исправить следующим образом:
import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

// Неизменяемый класс
public final class Storage<T> {
    // @NonNull
    private final T item;

    // Конструктор хранилища
    public Storage(T item, T alternative) {
        this.item = null != item 
                ? item 
                : requireNonNull(alternative, "alternative must be not null");
    }

    // Упрощенный метод получения объекта из хранилища
    public T get() {
        return this.item;
    }
}


Возможен вариант реализации с использованием Optional и функции, которая будет возвращать альтернативное значение:
import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;
import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public final class StorageOpt<T> {
    private final T item;

    public StorageOpt(T item, Supplier<T> alternative) {
        this.item = requireNonNull(
            ofNullable(item).orElseGet(alternative),
            "Non-null value has to be stored"
        );
    }

    public T get() {
        return item;
    }
}

// хранилище, принимающее функцию, которая вернёт альтернативное значение
StorageOpt<Integer> storageWithNumber = new StorageOpt<>(99, () -> -1);

